# Apply multiple styles with .style() method in D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

As I'm making my first steps into d3.js I couldn't help myself noticing its approach is very similar to jQuery.

My question is:

> When I need to modify multiple CSS properties of a `style` attribute
>   of matching element is there a shorthand approach, like jQuery or
>   ReactJS provide, like
>
> ```
> .style({width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'lightgreen'})`
> ```
>
> if I need to apply `width:100px`, `height:100px` and
>   `background-color:lightgreen` to a `<div>`.

Sure, I may chain those, but changing multiple properties this way may become tedious:

```js
d3
  .select('#test')
  .style('width','100px')
  .style('height','100px')
  .style('background-color','lightgreen')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script><div id="test"></div>
```

Or I may combine multiple desired properties within a class and assign that class with a `.classed()`, which may also overcomplicate CSS stylesheet when dynamic properties are required:

```js
d3
  .select('#test')
  .classed('testclass', true)
```

```css
.testclass {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script><div id="test"></div>
```

But those are not techniques I'm interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit (2021):

> ***Note:*** I claimed (in initial version of this answer) that there's no embedded method to solve the OP's problem. And, as of D3 v6.7.0 you still cannot pass your styles as an object directly to [`.style()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#selection_style) method

Two options you got by the time of this writing:

- loop through your styles object and apply the styles incrementally

```js
const style = {"width":"100px","height":"100px","background-color":"lightgreen"}

Object.entries(style).forEach(([prop,val]) => d3.select("#test").style(prop,val))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script><div id="test"></div>
```

- use [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) (solution massively upvoted down this thread)

Why I would discourage you from doing the latter:

- the referenced repo is long time archived (since 2017), so it may raise all sorts of interoperability issues, which may possibly be the reason for its [descending popularity](https://www.npmtrends.com/d3-selection-multi)
- under the hood that library [does exactly the same thing](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/eca50ebce40acbd75df342a00322fae89e1dd6e2/src/selection/styles.js#L10) (looping and applying styles incrementally)

So, whether you apply 1-line solution or add [up to 13kB](https://bundlephobia.com/package/d3-selection-multi@1.0.1) of legacy code to your application bundle for that sole purpose - is totally up to you.

Comment: @DeanMeehan: I'm not quite sure why you're referring to this one as it's about the way of manipulating style attribute with vanilla JS and related to assigning styles to `style.cssText` rather than `.style`,  where as my solution is effectively equivalent to `.style().style.style()` provided by d3 API.

Comment: I'd like to appologise. I havn't used D3 extensivily before so I wasn't aware that function was part of D3! :)

Comment: @DeanMeehan: No worries, mate. The richer the option set, the higher the chances to pick the optimal one.

Answer (score 8):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454337/5768908) is not correct (*"there's no such syntax documented in API reference"*), you can set multiple styles using [`d3-selection-multi`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi). Pay attention to the fact that you have to use the method `styles()`, not `style()`. So, in your case, it would be:

```
.styles({width:100, height:100, 'background-color':'lightgreen'})
```

Here is your snippet with that change:

```js
d3.select('#test')
  .styles({
    'width': '100px',
    'height': '100px',
    'background-color': 'lightgreen'
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

As `d3-selection-multi`is not part of the default bundle, you'll have to reference it separately.

Comment: Beware of using above approach as `d3-selection-multi` repository is archived and it will be no longer maintained, while [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454337/11299053) will still work regardless of D3.js version.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the `attr()` method and add the styles as part of the attribute of that particular tag being targeted:

```
d3.select("#test")
.attr("style", "width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lightgreen;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a better shorthand method for applying multiple styles to an element using Vanilla JavaScript. The ideal solution, in my opinion, is to apply a class to the element you wish to style that contains the multiple styles you wish to apply.

You could, of course, write a helper method that duplicates the JQuery method.

```
   function applyStyle(id, styles){
        Object.keys(styles).forEach(key => document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style",key +": "+styles[key]+";"));
    }
```

Comment: That's, basically, what I have already suggested with one minor difference, though - it uses pure JS `.getElementById()` rather than `d3.select()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access d3 node by calling `.node()` on needed selection, you can do smth like that:

```
item.node().style.cssText = `property: value; property2: value2`;
```

Also, if you use styled-components (react), you can simply insert your css like this:

```
item.node().style.cssText = PreviouslyDefinedCSS.toString();
```

where css is smth like this:

```
import { css } from "styled-components";
const PreviouslyDefinedCSS = css`
    your scss here
`;
```