# D3 Pass an Object to .attr or .style

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 selection:

```
let container = d3.select("div#container")
```

I want to append an object to it's styling - this object is dynamic that is why I cannot just hardcode it.

Example object:

```
let obj = {'style':'background-color:red;'}
```

Eample changes to object

```
if(x > 1) {
   obj = {'style':'background-color:green;'}
} else if (x < 0) {
   obj = {'style':'background-color:yellow;'}
}
```

I want to do something similar to

```
container.attr(obj); // Unsure if it should be attr or not
```

However, I am unsure how to obtain this. Any suggestions?

Comment: As of d3v4, you'll need to use d3-selection-multi, with which you can use.attrs or .styles, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209449/7106086). Otherwise, you could set multiple styles with: `.attr("style", "fill: orange; stroke: 1px")`  - you'll just need to convert your object to a string, but it's easier and cleaner to just go with d3-selection-multi.

Comment: @AndrewReid Works. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply multiple styles with .style() method in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454162/apply-multiple-styles-with-style-method-in-d3-js)